# Spring Data method name for specific purpose

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm new in Spring Data. I know that I can do it by `@Query` but I would like too learn more about how to write method names for specific purpose.

This is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEMBER_RECENT_CONTENT")
public class MemberRecentContent {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_ID", nullable = false)
private NCDMMember member;

@Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false)
private Long productId;

@Column(name = "VIEW_DATE", nullable = false)
private Date viewDate;

}
```

In my repository I have these two methods:

```
List<MemberRecentContent> findByMember_Id(Long memberId);
List<MemberRecentContent> findFirst10ByOrderByViewDateDesc();
```

Now I need to combine these two methods but I don't have any idea how to do this. I need to find 10 last record for specific MemberId. I have searched a lot but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I hope it might help . https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you can define as below:

```
List<MemberRecentContent> findFirst10ByMemberId(Long memberId, Sort sort);
```

and then, you can use:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "viewDate")
myRepository.findFirst10ByMemberId(memberId, sort)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helped me, but you made a little mistake in instantiating a Sort Object, the property that we need to pass is not column name like "VIEW_DATE" , we need to pass attribute name like "viewDate". any way thanks for opening the Paging and Sorting  world for me. :)